How to create a list dynamically in Prolog?
I have looked at the gazillions of other similar questions, but I haven't found a working solution, so I am asking this:
I have a rule:
check_prime(X) :-
  X > 0,
  X0 is X - 1, 
  (X =:= 1 -> true; 
   X =:= 2 -> true; 
   foreach(between(2, X0, T), X mod T =\= 0) -> true; false).

then I want to run:
B is [0], 
foreach( between(1, 50, T), 
         (check_prime(T) -> B2 = [B, T], write(B2); !)).

What this successfully does is write pairs of [0, primeNumber] to the console. I can alternatively do this:
B is [0],
foreach( between(1, 50, T), 
         (check_prime(T) -> (write(T), write(", ")); !)).

which actually prints everything in a pretty way, minus the lack of being a list, and the extra comma at the end.
This writing function is working through the solutions of check_prime(T) recursively, one solution at a time. I want to make a list of all of these solutions, but no matter what I try, I either cannot get object permanence (the written atom is something like _31415926), or I encounter a variety of errors.
How do I dynamically create a list of prime numbers since each one is found recursively?
Edit:
Yes, this is all the code I am using:


I have tried varying the "if true" branch, but it keeps having issues:




Where do you think the recursion is in this code?

Please post code you actually tried to solve this problem with.

The  "foreach(between(1, 50, T)...)" sets T to 1 and continues through the foreach command. if your true or false statement contains !, it will ignore that value (assuming you hit the !'s condition) and keep going. As for the "actual code", I have added two pictures for your reference.

That isn't recursion.

Code that builds a list does not need to use write.

That doesn't make sense, because if I execute "B is [0], foreach(between(1, 50, T), (check_prime(T) -> B2 is [T], write(B2); !)).", the output is "1, false" and it stops. If it isn't recursion, why would I only get a partial answer? There was also a version of the code (can't quite remember it) where I was given one prime at a time.

I am trying to confirm that I am building the list by writing the list.

Recursion is when a function/predicate calls itself.

We  have 3 options: (1) foreach creates a list from 1 to 50, and T is the entire list. (2) foreach loops through the values 1 to 50, and each time T becomes the new value. (3) foreach assigns T, runs its test, executes the condition, then undoes what it has done, reassigns T with the new value, and repeats. I am calling this recursion because we are undoing what we have done, going back up to a choice point (the choice of what to assign to T) and choosing a new value, unlike a loop which simply reassigns T and re-executes a procedure.

Thus number 3 would be recursion in the sense that the action re-executes itself with a new value of T at the choice point.

Something calling the same function repeatedly isn't the same as a function calling itself.

Okay, fair enough, though in my mind with the common factorial example, factorial(X) then calls factorial(X-1), and X-1 becomes the new X... but maybe there's small difference, sure. Now, how do I make the list?

This would be making  list using recursion: primes_between(A,B) = if A > B then [] elif A is prime then [A] + primes_between(A+1,B) else primes_between(A+1,B)

Can we get back on the topic of how to make the list?

That code IS making a list.

Then why can't I write the list to the console?

for simplicity, compare the code: >> B is [0], foreach(between(1, 50, T), (check_prime(T) -> (write(T), write(", ")); !)). << which writes each prime T as it is found, vs this code: >> B is [0], foreach(between(1, 50, T), (check_prime(T) -> B2 = [B, T]); !), write(B2). << which should write the list once we have gone through the entire range for T. However, the second code writes B2 = [0, T], which is not true because T is every number from 1 to 50.

There are several nice examples at https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Prolog

"If it isn't recursion, why would I only get a partial answer?" - because your cut ! kills backtracking. "(3) foreach assigns T, runs its test, executes the condition, then undoes what it has done, reassigns T with the new value, and repeats. I am calling this recursion because we are undoing what we have done, going back up to a choice point" - you are calling backtracking recursion; recursion doesn't behave like that, so this is unhelpful. "Then why can't I write the list to the console?" - because the backtracking undo is undoing list building, it needs to be outside backtracking.

TessellatingHeckler - thank you for the explanation! I guess I am convoluting backtracking and recursion. brebs - thank you for the example, I'll study those to get a better sense of how to build the list outside the backtracking.


How do I dynamically create a list of prime numbers?

Make check_prime check if a number is prime (and nothing else):
check_prime(1).
check_prime(2).
check_prime(X1) :-
    X1 > 2,
    succ(X0, X1),
    forall(between(2, X0, N), \+ (0 is X1 mod N)).

Then use it to make a list of primes, e.g:
?- findall(X, (between(1, 50, X), check_prime(X)), Primes).
Primes = [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47]

or
primes_to(X, Primes) :-
    numlist(1, X, Nums),
    include(check_prime, Nums, Primes).

?- primes_to(50, Primes).
Primes = [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47]

if you actually do want to do it recursively instead of conveniently, a builder that adds a counter onto the list of primes if the counter is prime, and doesn't if it isn't:
primes_to(0, []).

primes_to(Counter, [Counter|Primes]) :-
    check_prime(Counter),
    Counter0 is Counter - 1,
    primes_to(Counter0, Primes).

primes_to(Counter, Primes) :-
    \+ check_prime(Counter),
    Counter0 is Counter - 1,
    primes_to(Counter0, Primes).


?- primes_to(50, Primes).
Primes = [47, 43, 41, 37, 31, 29, 23, 19, 17, 13, 11, 7, 5, 3, 2, 1]


Ahh, this looks good. I'll probably implement the first two examples. My goal was to do what your second set of code does, use check_prime to just check if a number is prime, and then use primes_to so that the user can get all primes from 1 to a given input, as a list. I'll need to study the syntax for future reference (you don't have a single if-then-else!) but otherwise it looks clean and I can follow what it is doing.

your last code: recursive syntactically, iterative operationally, corecursive algorithmically (maybe). :)

Break it down like this!
check_primes/1 tests if a single (integer) number is a prime.
We define it like this: "for P to be prime, it must be greater than 1 and there may not be some integer P0 lying between 2 and P such that P0 evenly divides P":
check_prime(P) :- P > 1, \+ (between(2,P,P0), P0 < P, P mod P0 =:= 0).

Let's use it in combination with findall/3 in a sample query:
?- findall(X, (between(1,100,X), check_prime(X)), Primes).
Primes = [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97].

Or why not use it in a slighter bigger query?
?- findall(X, (between(1,2000,X), check_prime(X)), Primes).    
Primes = [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97,101,103,107,109,113,127,131,137,139,149,151,157,163,167,173,179,181,191,193,197,199,211,223,227,229,233,239,241,251,257,263,269,271,277,281,283,293,307,311,313,317,331,337,347,349,353,359,367,373,379,383,389,397,401,409,419,421,431,433,439,443,449,457,461,463,467,479,487,491,499,503,509,521,523,541,547,557,563,569,571,577,587,593,599,601,607,613,617,619,631,641,643,647,653,659,661,673,677,683,691,701,709,719,727,733,739,743,751,757,761,769,773,787,797,809,811,821,823,827,829,839,853,857,859,863,877,881,883,887,907,911,919,929,937,941,947,953,967,971,977,983,991,997,1009,1013,1019,1021,1031,1033,1039,1049,1051,1061,1063,1069,1087,1091,1093,1097,1103,1109,1117,1123,1129,1151,1153,1163,1171,1181,1187,1193,1201,1213,1217,1223,1229,1231,1237,1249,1259,1277,1279,1283,1289,1291,1297,1301,1303,1307,1319,1321,1327,1361,1367,1373,1381,1399,1409,1423,1427,1429,1433,1439,1447,1451,1453,1459,1471,1481,1483,1487,1489,1493,1499,1511,1523,1531,1543,1549,1553,1559,1567,1571,1579,1583,1597,1601,1607,1609,1613,1619,1621,1627,1637,1657,1663,1667,1669,1693,1697,1699,1709,1721,1723,1733,1741,1747,1753,1759,1777,1783,1787,1789,1801,1811,1823,1831,1847,1861,1867,1871,1873,1877,1879,1889,1901,1907,1913,1931,1933,1949,1951,1973,1979,1987,1993,1997,1999].


you must've meant "must be greater than 1" etc. :)

@WillNess. Thank you for your comment. It's better now -- I hope!

@WillNess. And I hope the implicit "integer/1" constraint is adequately expressed by using mod...
